# Writing to XML files on Servers

Tags: javascript, html, xml, comments

I have been working on a couple websites and need your help. I was wondering if there is a way to write to an XML file on  a server using javascript or HTML. I have searched all over the web for answers but can't seem to find answers.
Thanks, Wyatt

Comment: The server needs to accept an uploaded file. Your use case is unclear so far; what specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't a programming language, it can't write anything.

If you want to use JavaScript, then you need to use server side JavaScript. The usual tool for SSJS these days is [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). The [file system](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module will allow you to write to the disk.

Comment: Yes, I know that HTML isn't a language. That was a miss-write. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know about possibility to write xml via javascript Client-side.
but in the server side I know that you can write via php.
if you want I attach example. I hope that I helpe you.

```
<?php

function fnDOMAddElement2Start($doc='')
    {
        if(!$doc)
        {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load('Dictionary_user.xml');
        }
        $Dictionary_user = $doc->documentElement;
        #var_dump($Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->nodeName);
        $newWord = $doc->createElement('newWord');
        #$newWord->setAttribute('isbn','http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CHARSET=windows-1255"');


        $prop = $doc->createElement('Heb','bull');
        $newWord->appendChild($prop);
        $prop = $doc->createElement('Eng','bu');
        $newWord->appendChild($prop);


        $Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($newWord,$Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0));
        header("Content-type: text/xml");
        echo $doc->saveXML();
        $doc->save("Dictionary_user.xml");
    }
fnDOMAddElement2Start();
    ?>
```

the xml file seems like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Dictionarys>
  <newWord>
    <Heb>bull</Heb>
    <Eng>bu</Eng>
  <newWord>
    <Heb>Dog</Heb>
    <Eng>DO</Eng>
  </newWord>
  <newWord>
    <Heb>Cat</Heb>
    <Eng>ca</Eng>
  </newWord>
</Dictionarys>
```

Comment: -1. This answer is simply wrong. The question didn't ask about php (it didn't even hint about it being an option). It provides no information that is helpful in writing to server-side XML via client-side JavaScript, which is what the question asked.